# Multi-index dataframe throwing intermittent key error without .loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
level_1  0        0.000000
         1        0.000000
         2        0.000000
         3        0.000000
         4        0.000000
         5        0.000000
         6        0.000000
         7        0.000000
         8        0.000000
         9        0.000000
         10       0.000000
         11       0.000000
         12       0.000000
         13       0.000000
         14       0.000000
         15       0.000000
         16       0.000000
         17       0.000000
         18       0.000000
         19       0.000000
         20       0.000000
0        0      973.306931
         1     3722.277228
         2       73.722772
         3      974.000000
         4       19.752475
         5     1219.168317
         6       44.178218
         7      169.306931
         8     1141.158416
         9      150.396040
         10    1517.000000
         11     247.000000
         12      20.693069
         13      48.029703
         14    2239.603960
         15     124.485149
         16     409.900990
         17      13.861386
         18     458.415842
         19     103.000000
         20    3889.108911
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

I'm not clear on why when I access the frame `my_df0.loc[1]` above, I get the desired output, but when I call `my_df0[1]`, I get a keyerror:

```
KeyError: 1
```

I understand that there is no [1] index in the dataframe, but I can access .loc[1] as desired sometimes and not other times, dependent upon some criteria that I'm not aware of. Sometimes, the data in my frames does not throw the key error, and other times it does..

Comment: `my_df0[1]` would be looking for a __column__ labeled `1` and `my_df0.loc[1]` would be looking for a __row__ labeled `1`. (minimally reproducible frame `my_df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))`

Comment: That did get me thinking on the right track. I had to save the row data into a variable, and then the loc/xs/iloc slicing alternatives began to behave as expected.